# Rails Tutorial - Ch. 8 - ArgumentError in RSpec tests with 'before' line

Tags: rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm following the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl and I'm getting an unexpected error/failed test in section 8.2.6 Signing Out - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out?version=3.2#sec:signing_out

The code I used for my RSpec tests that is failing can be found in listing 8.28. The following code:

```
before { click_link "Sign out", method: :delete }
```

is giving the following error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
# (eval):2:in 'click_link'
# ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:35:in 'block (5 levels) in <top (required)>
```

I confirmed that my code is exactly as is shown in the example in Hartl's tutorial, but I'm still getting a failing test. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) method `click_link` [only takes a single parameter](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb), which is the name of the link you want to activate. So I think the code should really only be:

```
before { click_link "Sign Out" }
```

The rest of the code you had looks like the end of the sign_out action in thew view:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: => :delete %>
```

By using Capybara to click the link, it should already be utilizing the above code inside the view, so the last junk seems like duplication.

I would just remove the "method: :delete" and see what you get.

Comment: Yup, just got a response from Michael Hartl on Twitter confirming that it was indeed a bug. https://twitter.com/#!/railstutorial/status/173211566425128960